# LWUIT Dialog problem with dispose()

Tags: java-me, dialog, lwuit, lwuit-resource-editor, resource-editor

I am making a dialog with a command. This command must close the dialog and go back to the previous form, but it is not working as expected. When I press the command, it closes the dialog but the form do not go back.

I am using the resource editor. State machine controls the app´s navigation.

The code inside the command´s logic is:

`dialog.dispose();

StateMachine.back();`

Is `dispose()` the method that I must use to close my dialog?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: StateMachine is a class generated from the LWUIT Resource editor. It allows, among other things, manage the app´s navigation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Nirmal said disposing the dialog goes to the previous form so while your call to "back()" works as expected your call to dispose() breaks that logic.

You can override the postShow method for the form you are showing and detect the case of leaving the dialog (just turn on a flag when you need to go back) and call the back method when the form is shown in that condition.

Answer (score 2):

dont call `StateMachine.back()` just use `dialog.dispose();`

Comment: I need to call <code>StateMachine.back</code> because i need to do back to a previous form. I mean, I need to close the dialog and in the form, go back to a previous form.
But apart from this. When I call dispose, the dialog close but the commands´ functionality works bad.

Answer (score 2):

There is another solution : try to use the `protected void onShowCompleted()` method that you must implement in your `Form`. And declare a `boolean` variable in your `Form` ( for example `private boolean isDialogShown;` ), then `in the constructor` of your `Form` set that boolean variable to `false`, and just before the code of opening the `Dialog` set its value to `true`. Then in the code of the `protected void onShowCompleted()` test if it is true , and if it is true then set it to false and perform the back action : `backForm.showBack();`